# Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multilabel-indicator and binary targets

Tags: scikit-learn, pytorch

I am getting a error : Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multilabel-indicator and binary targets. wenn I try to use accuracy_score

I have tried to update sickst-learn, but it didn't work for me.

This is the code:

def mean_class_accuracy(scores, labels):
"""Calculate mean class accuracy.

```
Args:
    scores (list[np.ndarray]): Prediction scores for each class.
    labels (list[int]): Ground truth labels.

Returns:
    np.ndarray: Mean class accuracy.
"""
pred = np.argmax(np.stack(scores, axis=0), axis=-1)
mean_class_acc = accuracy_score(labels, pred)
return mean_class_acc
```

def calculate(self, preds: List[np.ndarray],
labels: List[Union[int, np.ndarray]]) -> Dict:
"""Compute the metrics from processed results.

```
    Args:
        preds (list[np.ndarray]): List of the prediction scores.
        labels (list[int | np.ndarray]): List of the labels.

    Returns:
        dict: The computed metrics. The keys are the names of the metrics,
        and the values are corresponding results.
    """
    eval_results = OrderedDict()
    #labels = np.stack(self.labels, axis=0)
    metric_options = copy.deepcopy(self.metric_options)
    for metric in self.metrics:
        if metric == 'top_k_accuracy':
            topk = metric_options.setdefault('top_k_accuracy',
                                             {}).setdefault(
                                                 'topk', (1))

            if not isinstance(topk, (int, tuple)):
                raise TypeError('topk must be int or tuple of int, '
                                f'but got {type(topk)}')

            if isinstance(topk, int):
                topk = (topk, )

            top_k_acc = top_k_accuracy(preds, labels, topk)
            for k, acc in zip(topk, top_k_acc):
                eval_results[f'top{k}'] = acc

        if metric == 'mean_class_accuracy':
            mean1 = mean_class_accuracy(preds, labels)
            eval_results['mean1'] = mean1
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example with random values ? maybe using `torch.rand`?